# How to get tags inside of CDATA with Xpath3 on Anypoint Mule?

Tags: xpath, mule, cdata, anypoint-studio

I am trying to get the tag `Decision` inside a PDP response with Xpath3 on Anypoint mule.

This is the response of the PDP:

```
<ns:getDecisionResponse xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
   <ns:return><![CDATA[<Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"><Result><Decision>Indeterminate</Decision><Status><StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:syntax-error"/><StatusMessage>Invalid request  : DOM of request element can not be created from String</StatusMessage></Status></Result></Response>]]></ns:return>
</ns:getDecisionResponse>
```

The problem is that I can't access the tags which are inside of the CDATA.
This is what I was trying to do:

```
#[xpath3('/ns:getDecisionResponse/ns:return/(the problem is here...)',payload, 'STRING')]
```

Thanks in advance!

Juan Andrés

Comment: There are no tags inside CDATA. That's what CDATA means: "the things in here may look like tags, but they aren't: they are to be treated as character data". If CDATA has been used incorrectly, as here, then you will have to extract the content of the CDATA as text, and submit it to an XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex expression to remove the CDATA from your XPATH3 as following :-

```
 <logger message="#[xpath3('/*:getDecisionResponse/*:return',payload, 'STRING').replaceAll(&quot;[^\\u0009\\u000A\\u000D\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD\\x{10000}-\\x{10FFFF}]&quot;, &quot;&quot;)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

reference :- http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-sanitize-xml-string.html
Now once you get the xml here from your **CDATA** you need to perform another XPATH3 extraction to get you required value from the the xml